# Cannot call method 'convertScenarioOutlinesToScenarios' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, bdd, protractor, cucumberjs

I've been reading up on protractor and it looks like a great way to put automated functional tests in place on my team's AngularJS system. I was following the setup steps [here](https://github.com/AndrewKeig/protractor-cucumber) so I can continue using gherkin to define feature files (like in plain cucumber), but I keep getting the below error when I run `$ cucumber.js` step on the readme.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/ast/assembler.js:105
      self.getCurrentFeature().convertScenarioOutlinesToScenarios();
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'convertScenarioOutlinesToScenarios' of undefined
    at Object.finish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/ast/assembler.js:105:32)
    at Object.handleEof [as eof] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/parser.js:70:20)
    at Lexer.scan (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/node_modules/gherkin/lib/gherkin/lexer/en.js:1049:21)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/parser.js:26:25)
    at Object.getFeatures (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/runtime.js:30:35)
    at Object.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/runtime.js:16:37)
    at Object.runSuiteWithConfiguration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli.js:19:15)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli.js:12:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js:4:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

All of the setup steps up to that point worked just fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/spec/cucumber and https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/cucumberConf.js for an example